# How do I stop my nested loop? It loops over and over again. I only want 18 results not 81

Tags: delphi, multidimensional-array, 2d, nested-loops

[image]

```
var
  arrGame: array [1 .. 9, 1 .. 9] of char;
  arrPlanets: array [1 .. 9, 1 .. 9] of char;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
{$R+}

procedure TfrmQ3.btnQ3_1StartGameClick(Sender: TObject);    
var
  i, j: integer;
  cGame: char; 
begin 
  btnQ2Play.Enabled := true;
  redQ3GameBoard.Clear; 
  redQ3incorrect.Clear; 
  for i := 1 to 9 do
  begin 
    for j := 1 to 9 do 
      arrGame[i,j] := '-'; 
  end; 

  for i := 1 to 9 do 
  begin
    for j := 1 to 5 do
    begin
      redQ3GameBoard.Lines.Add(arrGame[i,j]+ ' ' + arrGame[i,
        j] + ' ' + arrGame[i,j] + ' ' + arrGame[i,j] + ' ' + arrGame[i,
        j] + ' ' + arrGame[i,j] + ' ' + arrGame[i,j] + ' ' + arrGame[i,
        j] + ' ' + arrGame[i,j]);
    end; 
  end; 
end;

end.
```

On the top left is what my code is produces. The results I am trying to get are on the bottom left.

[image: Photo of computer screen with IDE as described above]

Comment: Doesn't your [Print screen key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Print_Screen) work? :) Anyhow, 9 * 9 = 81, so you will iterate 81 times.

Comment: Oh, haha, sorry, I was using my tablet to access the internet, I'll use my laptop next time.  How would I make it stop in such a way that I get a 9 by 9 output?

Comment: Generally, we prefer that you post your code as *text* here at Stack Overflow. Just so you know for your next question.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind, thank you

Comment: Don't "keep that in mind". Please edit this question to include your code.

Comment: If you need to understand *why* pictures of code are not helpful, see : [An image of your code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: all sorted. I'm still figuring things out on here, my bad

Comment: You say: ***I only want 18 results not 81*** So why are you looping 9 * 9 times (81 times) in the first `for` loop pairs, instead of 2 * 9 times (18 times)? Why are you looping 9 * 5 times (45 times) in the second `for` loop pair? In the first `for` loop pair you output 81 times the character `'-'`, ok. But why do you output a line of 9 chars (plus spaces) 45 times? Do you know that you can multiply 9 with 2 and arrive at 18 as you state your wish to be, in the title of your question.

Comment: I realised it was a logic error. It's all sorted now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have this code:

```
for i = 1 to 9 do
  for j = 1 to 9 do
    List.Lines.Add(...)
```

The statement

```
List.Lines.Add(...)
```

will run 9 × 9 = 81 times. Since this statement adds a line, you will get 81 lines. (Also, with nine identical values on each line! For example, when i = 4 and j = 6, you will print the value `arrGame[4, 6]` nine times on that row. Can you see how that is the case?)

This is the flaw in your logic. You only want 9 lines, but each line should contain 9 components. Hence, you need to redesign the code.

Since this seems like homework, I will not give you the solution in detail. Instead, I'll give you the following command-line program to study:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

var
  Grid: array of array of Char;

const
  N = 9;

var
  i, j: Integer;
  s: string;

function GetRandomLetter: Char;
begin
  Result := Chr(Ord('A') + Random(Ord('Z') - Ord('A') + 1));
end;

begin

  try
    try

      Randomize;
      SetLength(Grid, N, N);

      // Build grid
      for i := 0 to N - 1 do
        for j := 0 to N - 1 do
          Grid[i, j] := GetRandomLetter;

      // Draw grid
      for i := 0 to N - 1 do
      begin
        s := Grid[i, 0];
        for j := 1 to N - 1 do
          s := s + #32 + Grid[i, j];
        Writeln(s);
      end;


    except
      on E: Exception do
        Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    Writeln('Press Return to exit.');
    Readln;
  end;

end.
```

[image: Screenshot of program output: a 9-by-9 grid of capital letters.]

Comment: I see now. Thank you highly, I'll try it out